# Join Customer Address custom attribute to Order Address Collection

Tags: collection, sql, customer-address, custom-attributes

I would like to join custom `customer/address` attributes with the `sales_flat_order_address` table and `sales/order_address_collection` resource model.

The attributes are called `gmap_lng` and `gmap_lat`, and I set them via:

```
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$address->setGmapLng('value');
$address->setGmapLat('value');
$address->save();
```

I would like to join these attribute values in the `sales/order_address_collection` where there are matching `customer_id` values, but I'm not sure how to use join():

```
$orderAddresses = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_address_collection');
$orderAddresses->getSelect()->join(??,??,??);
```

I have `gmap_lng` and `gmap_lat` columns ready to be filled in `sales_flat_order_address`.

Thanks!

Comment: what tables do you want to join? as I understood from the question: `sales_flat_order_address` with itself?

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `getSelect` on a collection, you will be working with a `Zend_Db_Select` object. You can read about it here:

> http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join

Now regarding your question, you didn't mention *how* you've installed the `gmap_lat` and `gmap_lng` attributes. I'm assuming you've done so as an EAV attribute. As such, EAV makes it hard for us to "simply" join with the `sales_flat_order_address` info. Here's what it takes:

```
$orderAddresses = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_address_collection');
$read           = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$gmapLat        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer_address', 'gmap_lat'); 
$gmapLng        = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('customer_address', 'gmap_lng'); 

$orderAddresses->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('caev_gmap_lat' => 'customer_address_entity_varchar'),
        '(caev_gmap_lat.entity_id = main_table.customer_address_id) AND ' . 
        '(' . $read->quoteInto('caev_gmap_lat.attribute_id = ?', $attribute->getId()) . ')',
        array('gmap_lat' => 'caev_gmap_lat.value')
    )
    ->joinLeft(
        array('caev_gmap_lng' => 'customer_address_entity_varchar'),
        '(caev_gmap_lng.entity_id = main_table.entity_id) AND ' . 
        '(' . $read->quoteInto('caev_gmap_lng.attribute_id = ?', $attribute->getId()) . ')',
        array('gmap_lat' => 'caev_gmap_lng.value')
    );
```

Here's a breakdown of what it does:

- Get the sales order address collection
- Get an instance of a DB read connection
- Load the `gmap_lat` and `gmap_lng` attribute models
- Join them with the address collection

Fetching the attribute models allows you to consistently get the right attribute ID, which you'll need to *left* join the data to the main table.

Note that I'm assuming your attributes were created as `varchar` in type. Adapt the tables if you store them as another type.